# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor jquery-1.10.0.js

Tags: javascript, django

When I load a **Django** application on Chrome, which uses jquery. I receive this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor jquery-1.10.0.js: (number of line)".
```

- Can be a version problem of Chrome or jquery-1-10.0.js ?

My chrome version is "Versión 37.0.2062.124 m".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a problem with Chrome, it's an error that occurs inside the jQuery source file. You shoulod **replace it** with another one, because it contains an error.

You can either download a newer version or the same version from another source. I suggest you **[the official one](http://jquery.com/download/)**.